# Visual Studio Code: IntelliSense stopped finding core c++ includes in MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, xcode, intellisense

In OSX Monterey, after upgrading a Homebrew install of clang, something about the default C++ headers got screwed up.

I am able to compile from the terminal just fine; it works both if I use the system clang (`/usr/bin/clang`, which is still the default and the result of `which clang`), or if I use Homebrew's more recent clang (`/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/14.0.6_1/bin/clang`).

However, in VSCode, none of the default C++ headers can be found.

For example, if I `#include <iostream>`, IntelliSense red-squiggles it and complains `cannot open source file "iostream" C/C++(1696)`.

I have tried restarting VSCode and my machine, I've tried `Reset IntelliSense Database` from the command palette. To the `C_Cpp > System Include Path` setting, I've tried adding `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`; and to the `C_Cpp > Mac Framework Path` setting I've tried explicitly adding `/System/Library/Frameworks/`. None of these things have fixed the issue.

After upgrading, I also had some issues with clang itself not finding the system includes which were fixed by reinstalling the XCode developer tools.

- How do I debug why IntelliSense can't find the standard headers?
- How do repair this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed after

- Upgrading XCode (not just the developer tools, but the entire app; autoupdates had stopped due to limited disk space), and
- Disabling the C++ extension and then re-enabling it.

Upgrading XCode by itself did not fix the issue, it didn't work until C++ was disabled and then re-enabled. I don't know if the former was actually necessary or not.

Restarting the machine and bouncing VSCode itself was not sufficient either.

I'm not sure *why* it was necessary to toggle the extension, but it's certainly easier than uninstalling and re-installing VSCode (which was the next thing I was about to try).